# Weird syntax error in MySQL Workbench 6.3

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

My code reads as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS store;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer (

customer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

middle_name VARCHAR(20),

last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,

email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,

usr_pword CHAR(10) NOT NULL,

reg_date DATE,

PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),

FOREIGN KEY (rental_id) REFERENCES (rental_id),

UNIQUE (email)

);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rental (

rental_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

date_out DATE NOT NULL,

date_in DATE NOT NULL,

cost INTEGER NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (rental_id),

FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES (customer_id),

FOREIGN KEY (game_id) REFERENCES (game_id)

);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS game (

game_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,

game_name VARCHAR(60),

game_publisher VARCHAR(20),

PRIMARY KEY (game_id),

FOREIGN KEY (rental_id) REFERENCES (rental_id)

);
```

and i get the error: 
Error code 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax... near 'rental_id UNIQUE (email));'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line has invalid syntax for declaring a foreign key:

```
FOREIGN KEY (rental_id) REFERENCES (rental_id),
```

You have to declare the referenced table in any foreign key definition. Then after the table name, declare the referenced column(s) in that table inside parentheses. Example:

```
FOREIGN KEY (rental_id) REFERENCES `ReferencedTable` (rental_id),
```

You should learn to read SQL syntax documentation, because it holds the answer to this question and others. For example, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html shows the syntax for a foreign key reference:

```
reference_definition:
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
      [MATCH FULL | MATCH PARTIAL | MATCH SIMPLE]
      [ON DELETE reference_option]
      [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

Notice how `tbl_name` follows the `REFERENCES` keyword, then after that a parenthesized list of columns.

Checking syntax reference documentation should be your first method of resolving syntax errors like the one you got.

Comment: Even without reading the documentation it should be obvious that a table name is needed in a foreign key constraint. The whole point of FK is to relate to another table, and it needs to know what table.

Comment: @Barmar, right, but it might be reasonable to expect a DBMS to know about unambiguous cases and to do the right thing. In this case there's exactly one table with a primary key called `rental_id`. Another example is that columns in a JOIN query don't have to be qualified with the table name if they're unambiguous. Also, (although MySQL doesn't support this option) foreign keys in SQL may omit the referenced column names if they're the same as the FK column names.

Comment: thanks, but when i do that i get an error claiming i don't have the key i'm referring to but i do, would you happen to know why? (the only change in my code is having the table names before the foreign key reference)

Comment: Exactly: Error code 1072. Key column 'rental_id' doesn't exist in table

Comment: @Harvey I can't even guess unless you show what command you tried to run. Please edit your answer above and add this information.

Comment: @BillKarwin CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS store;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer (
customer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
middle_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
usr_pword CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
reg_date DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),
FOREIGN KEY (rental_id) 
REFERENCES rental (rental_id),
UNIQUE (email)
);

Comment: the rest of my code is edited in the same way, sorry for how poorly it's organised, i'm new to the website.

Comment: And table rental exists? And has a key column rental_id?

Comment: @BillKarwin yeah, i'm pretty sure, the only thing that i changed in my original code was to do with the foreign keys

Comment: Well, since you got an error trying to create the first table, the sequence of SQL statements is interrupted. SO the second table may not have been created. A foreign key that references a table that doesn't exist yet will fail.